# Unable to navigate to child state in ui router

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I have state as follow. I can navigate from `app` to `app.child1`. But I cannot navigate from `app.child1` to `app.child1.child2`. There is no error in browser console. Do note that I am developing an ionic application but i dont think that this is ionic issue.

```
app.state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: '',
    controller: ''
})

.state('app.child1', {
    url: '/app',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: '',
            controller: ''
        }
    }
})

.state('app.child1.child2', {
    url: '/app/child1/child2',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: '',
            controller: ''
        }
    }
})
```

Navigation:

```
<button ui-sref="app.child1.child2">Change Page</button>
```

Comment: make sure in your `app.child1`'s template, there exist `<div ui-view></div>` directive, if not your `app.child1.child2` will not get populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/I3HJujc1UKxeXvYmvM1E?p=preview)

There are few issues with the state definition, which are covered in comments below:

```
  .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'app.tpl.thml',
    controller: 'appCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.child1', {
    // child1 should have url part /child1
    // while the /app is inherited from parent
    //url: '/app', 
    url:'/child1',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'child1.tpl.html',
        controller: 'child1Ctrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.child1.child2', {
    // all parts are inherited from parents
    // so just /child2 is enough
    //url: '/app/child1/child2',
    url: '/child2',
    views: {
      // we target named view in a grand parent
      // not in parent, we need to use the absolute name
      // 'menuContent': {
      'menuContent@app': {
        templateUrl: 'child2.tpl.html',
        controller: 'child2Ctrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

These links will work now

```
<a href="#/app/child1">
<a href="#/app/child1/child2">
<a ui-sref="app.child1">
<a ui-sref="app.child1.child2">
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/I3HJujc1UKxeXvYmvM1E?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Your states don't have a template (`templateUrl: ''`).  They should have a template with `ui-view` directive where it's child state can be injected.